# Can I use partitions of activity diagram to place activity instead of actions?

Tags: uml

I'm making an activity diagram and I'm using activities instead of actions because I'm not going into much detail in the steps being described. I want to separate the activities in the partitions but all I've been reading about partitions says that in partitions I can place actions. But it doesn't say anything about placing activities there. Look this pic explaining it:

[image: partitionspic]

The image was taken from [this page](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html).

Comment: [uml-diagrams.org: Activity Partition](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html#partition) says "_..An activity partition is activity **group for actions** that have some common characteristic.._" so your understanding is probably right. Why you can't/don't want use actions?

Answer (score 1):

In an activity diagram, actions and (sub-)activities are shown with the same representation. The only difference is that an activity may contain a smaller diagram within its bounds.

If you don't make use of the feature that you can draw a diagram within the shape of activity, there is no way to tell for sure if a task on the diagram is really an undividable task or if it is really an activity that doesn't specify its details.
If you keep that in mind, then it should be clear that swimlanes could just as well contain sub-activities of the activity you are modelling.

Comment: Let say Im using activities and the activities have actions inside. Can I still place those activities inside the lanes of a partition.